# Why zuul doesn't change dowstream service redirect ip in http header location?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a problem in reverse proxy using zuul.

My app has a downstream service that used spring security for authentication. This project redirects to login.jsp when user requests Index.jsp.

My zuul configuration in zuul project is this:

```
 zuul:
  #addProxyHeaders : true
  #ignoreSecurityHeaders: false
  routes:
    trp:
      path: /app/**
      url: http://192.168.251.141:5050/app
server:
    port: 80
```

But when a user calls http://localhost/app/Index.jsp application redirect to http://192.168.251.141:5050/app/Login.jsp

After googling that I found response is like this:

```
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type    text/html
Date     Mon, 26 Dec 2016 09:02:44 GMT
Location    http://192.168.251.141:5050/app/Login.jsp
Transfer-Encoding    chunkedVary    
Accept-Encoding  
X-Application-Context    application:80
X-Content-Type-Options    nosniff
X-Frame-Options    SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block
```

Why is the `Location` header http://192.168.251.141:5050/app/Login.jsp? And why doesn't Zuul change this ip?

This configuration works in nginx by using the `proxy_redirect` module.  How can change location by zuul routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zuul doesn't rewrite any responses by default. Your downstream service would have to know how to deal with the `X-Forwarded-Host` header that zuul adds and redirect there. Another option would be to write a zuul filter that rewrites the Location header.

Comment: my downstream service using spring security for authentication. why spring security dose not handle this ?

Comment: how would it know where to redirect to? probably a question for spring security

Comment: why spring security form login redirect dose not rewrite responce location with X-Forwarded-Host?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: can u send zuul filter example for rewrite response by routes that define?

Comment: I don't have an example to send actually.